# Responsive Design of Form Elements

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I am learning Responsive design of web pages. During the learning I have created a basic page sections and it is looking fine but web form elements are not responding properly to Browser resizing. 
Here is the code I have written:

```
    <!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Term</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="reset.css" type="text/css"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">

    <style>
    body {

        font-size:1em;
        text-align: center;
    }
    #header { 
        height: 5em;
                background:#e2ebc3;
                max-width:1300px;
    }

    #mainContent {
        width: 69%;
        max-width:900px;
        min-width:300px;
        float: left;
        background:#F2F5F4;
            position: relative;
    }

    #sideContentWrapper {
        max-width:400px;
        min-width:150px;
        width: 30%;
        float: left;
        margin-right:0.5em;
    }
    #sideContent {
        margin-left: 1em;
        min-height: 20em;
        background:#F4F2F5;
    }

        label {
            float: left;
            width: 6em;
            text-align: left;
        }
        #frmterm {
            padding: 2em;
            width: 90%;
            max-width:800px;
            position: relative;
        }

        /* form elemnts are not working properly. Do I need the below css? */
        #frmterm fieldset,#frmterm fieldset legend, #frmterm fieldset ol, #frmterm fieldset li {width: 100%;}

        #frmterm, li {
            text-align: left;
            margin-bottom: 1.5em;
            width: 100%;
        }
        #frmterm input {
            width: 80%; 
        }

        #frmterm textarea {
            width: 80%;
            height:200%;
            display: block; 
        }

        #frmterm fieldset:nth-child(2)  {
            text-align: center;
        }

    @media screen and (max-width:800px) and (min-width:540px)
    {
        /* Tablets */
        #sideContentWrapper {
            min-width:150px;
            width: 30%;
            float: right;
            margin-right:0.25em;

        }
        #sideContent {
            margin-left: 0.5em;
            min-height: 20em;
            background:#999; /*  marker */
        }

    }
    @media screen and (max-width:540px)
    {
        /* Smartphone */

                #frmterm, li {margin-bottom: 0.5em;}

        #sideContentWrapper {

            display:none;
        }
        #mainContent {
            width: 100%;
        }

        </style>
    </head>
    <body>

<div id="header">Header</div>

<div id="mainContent">

      <form action="" id="frmterm">
          <fieldset>
              <legend>
                  <ol>
                      <li><label for="terms">Term:</label><input id="terms" type="text" value="" /></li>
                      <li><label for="summary">Summary:</label><input id="summary" type="text" value="" /></li>
                      <li><label for="category">Category:</label><textarea id="category"  ></textarea></li>

                  </ol>
              </legend>
          </fieldset>
          <fieldset>
              <button type="submit">Submit</button>
          </fieldset>
      </form>
</div>

<div id="sideContentWrapper">
    <div id="sideContent">
   Side Content
 </div>
</div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

- **Example resolution where problem can be visible**:

At 980*1280, form elements are touching sidebar, whereas I have given 80% width to form elements. To report this, I have used Responsive Design View of Firefox.

- The below code has helped a little in above problem:

  ```
  #frmterm fieldset,#frmterm fieldset legend, #frmterm fieldset ol, #frmterm fieldset li {width: 100%;}
  ```

  but I am not sure why I need to mention it in CSS.
- I am not much interested on HTML betterment until and unless that is
  mandatory. I am learning it so I am learning it one by one. I want to
  correct it using CSS.  If possible please provide, important CSS
  considerations for Form elements in responsive design.
- Also, Do I need Viewport Meta Tag. I see no benefits in my web page
  when I resize webpage on Laptop browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the approx. solution.

```
* { 
            -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
            -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }
```

I applied it to input and textarea but that did not worked. So, which element exactly need it ?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a CSS only solution that may or may not work for you:

original: http://jsfiddle.net/brandonbabb/JnPBm/

modified: http://jsfiddle.net/brandonbabb/gM8fp/

I added comments in the css and did not change any html.

I recommend to most people not to use em values unless you need to. ems are hard to interpret unless you have a lot of experience working with them, they are also less intuitive than percent values at first glance.

Remember to add the following code whenever using ems:

```
html {font-size: 100%}
```

Also, the viewport tag is only for mobile devices.

Comment: I see it is good looking now. But not sure what you did there as I was removing your css one by one and it was still working. Your suggestions are looking important. Voted up.

Comment: Any comment on my above comment on box-sizing. Where exactly it is needed on those markup?

Comment: The most important part of the changes I made was the following code: #frmterm{top:20px; bottom:20px; left:20px; right:20px; position: absolute;}  You should do some research into absolute positioning inside of relative positioned elements.

Comment: The * symbol specifies that all elements are using it, which is probably the best implementation of box sizing, so your box sizing code is fine.

Comment: hmm! I have not noticed absolute positioning you have done. Though locally that change does not do anything. About box sizing, I was thinking of applying to minimum number of element where exactly it is needed. But you said it is good to apply to all. So, I will leave thinking about that. Thanks.